# How to create a webservice using node.js to insert data into mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, web-services

I've a table in mysql that i need to be populated by calling a webservice.

The catch is, I would like to pass the data to be inserted into the database as parameters to the webservice.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MySQL module

http://npmjs.com/mysql

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'me',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM table`, (error, data) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            res.json(data)
        } 
    });
});

app.post('/update/user/:id?', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const username = req.body.username;
    connection.query(`UPDATE MyGuests SET username='${username}' WHERE id=${id}`, (error, data) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            res.json(data)
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand that I should use the MYSQL module. how do i pass parameters to insert data into a table to the js file?

Comment: yes, thank you, however i noticed a minor issue .. => is not necessary between (error) & {.

Comment: Oh ya, silly me, why the hey I'll put a fat array in a if statesmen